# Sending Streaming Data as JSON in Java/Scala

Tags: java, json, scala

I'm used to python and using the Scala Spark Streaming libraries to handle real-time Twitter streaming data.  Right now, I'm able to send as a string, however, my streaming service requires JSON.  Is there a way I can easily adapt my code to send as JSON dictionary instead of a String?

```
%scala

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs._
import java.util.concurrent._

val namespaceName = "hubnamespace"
val eventHubName = "hubname"
val sasKeyName = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
val sasKey = "key"
val connStr = new ConnectionStringBuilder()
            .setNamespaceName(namespaceName)
            .setEventHubName(eventHubName)
            .setSasKeyName(sasKeyName)
            .setSasKey(sasKey)

val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
val eventHubClient = EventHubClient.create(connStr.toString(), pool)

def sendEvent(message: String) = {
  val messageData = EventData.create(message.getBytes("UTF-8"))
  // CONVERT IT HERE?
  eventHubClient.get().send(messageData)
  System.out.println("Sent event: " + message + "\n")
}

import twitter4j._
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory
import twitter4j.Twitter
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder

val twitterConsumerKey = "key"
val twitterConsumerSecret = "key"
val twitterOauthAccessToken = "key"
val twitterOauthTokenSecret = "key"

val cb = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
  .setOAuthConsumerKey(twitterConsumerKey)
  .setOAuthConsumerSecret(twitterConsumerSecret)
  .setOAuthAccessToken(twitterOauthAccessToken)
  .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(twitterOauthTokenSecret)

val twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build())
val twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance()

val query = new Query(" #happynewyear ")
query.setCount(100)
query.lang("en")
var finished = false
while (!finished) {
  val result = twitter.search(query)
  val statuses = result.getTweets()
  var lowestStatusId = Long.MaxValue
  for (status <- statuses.asScala) {
    if(!status.isRetweet()){
      sendEvent(status.getText())
    }
    lowestStatusId = Math.min(status.getId(), lowestStatusId)
    Thread.sleep(2000)
  }
  query.setMaxId(lowestStatusId - 1)
}

 eventHubClient.get().close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scala has no native way to convert string to Json, you'll need to use an external library. I recommend using `Jackson`.  If you use gradle you can add a dependency like this: `compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.12")`. (Use appropriate scala version)

Then, you can simply convert your data object to JSON like this:

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

val json = valueToTree(messageData)
```

I'd strongly recommend you put your effort in Jackson, you'll need it a lot if you work with JSON.